# async LoadImage routine hanging

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, async-await, loadimage

I have a Windows 8 app that I'm attempting to load an image using the following code:

```
    private async Task<BitmapImage> LoadImage(IStorageFile storageFile)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LoadImage started");

        try
        {
            // Set the image source to the selected bitmap
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = null;

            // Ensure a file was selected
            if (storageFile != null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LoadImage::OpenAsync");
                // Ensure the stream is disposed once the image is loaded
                using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("New Bitmap");
                    // Set the image source to the selected bitmap
                    bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();


                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Set Source");
                    bitmapImage.SetSource(fileStream);
                }
            }

            return bitmapImage;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        } // End of catch
        finally
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Load image finished");
        }

        return null;
    }
```

When I run the code it sometimes works. But other times it simply hangs and I get the following output:

```
LoadImage started
LoadImage::OpenAsync
```

Am I using `storageFile.OpenAsAsync` incorrectly? My storage file is the result of a call to:

```
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;

        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");

        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
          var loadImageTask = LoadImage(currentStorageFile);
          loadImageTask.Wait();
          DisplayImage.Source = loadImageTask.Result;
        }
```

So it should not be a sandbox issue (and there is no exception).

Could anyone point me in the right path?

Comment: Do you have a call to `Task.Wait` or `Task.Result` somewhere further up your call stack?

Comment: Yes, I have:

            var loadImageTask = LoadImage(currentStorageFile);
            loadImageTask.Wait();
            DisplayImage.Source = loadImageTask.Result;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `Task.Wait` and `Task.Result` is causing the deadlock. I explain this in detail [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [in a recent MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

In short, when you `await` a `Task` that has not yet completed, by default it will capture a "context" and use that to resume the `async` method. In your case, this is the UI context. However, when you call `Wait` (or `Result`), you're blocking the UI thread, so the `async` method cannot complete.

To fix this, use `await` instead of `Wait`/`Result`, and use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere you can.